# Parse facebook login null pointer exception

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make facebook login with parse on my andorid app, but I get the following error:

> 08-28 21:24:34.441  10524-10524/com.example.hristijan.likeout E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.hristijan.likeout, PID: 10524
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>               at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getLogger(LoginManager.java:391)
>               at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logCompleteLogin(LoginManager.java:414)
>               at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.startLogin(LoginManager.java:384)
>               at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginManager.java:262)
>               at com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.authenticateAsync(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:150)
>               at com.parse.ParseAuthenticationProvider.logInAsync(ParseAuthenticationProvider.java:57)
>               at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInAsync(ParseFacebookUtils.java:259)
>               at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:155)
>               at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:167)
>               at com.example.hristijan.likeout.MainActivity.facebookLogin(MainActivity.java:74)
>               at com.example.hristijan.likeout.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4763)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19821)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)

Here's the code:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, null, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (user == null) {
                //Canceled fb connection
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (user.isNew()) {
                //Registered with fb
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "REGISTERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Logged in with fb
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGGED IN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, to solve this you need to add this on your `androidmanifest.xml`, you can get the `facebook_app_id` on your app dashboard.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

After that I need to add the `FacebookActivity` too.

```
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
      android:configChanges=
             "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
      android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Just remember to put those lines inside the `application` tag.

Found the solution [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)